# What are the specs for the camera offered in the kit for Project Tango

Tags: google-project-tango

How small objects can be scanned? What is the minimum distance can I get to the object with the camera? Where can I find the specs of the development kit?

Answer (score 0):

Google has neglected to answer most of these questions - it is disappointing that they seem unable or unwilling to provide key information. Therefore, anecdotally from experience...

1)  How small ?   Given the fact that point cloud scans are inherently noisy, most people doing statistical based processing are running voxels from 1 to 5 cm - myself, I find 2 cm is workable, 1 can lead to noise, and also poor behavior of feature detectors because point density gets too low - so that's resolution - for size, pick a multiple -  it is resolution that will most concern you however, just because you can see it doesn't mean you have the resolution to accurately resolve it

2)  Minimum distance -  10-15 cm is a good rule of thumb - below that range and things quickly become invisible, I think due to geometric constraints on the visual light field projection

3) Specs on the development kit -- https://developers.google.com/project-tango/hardware/tablet is what google provides - yes, for any serious practitioner, pretty much laughably useless.

Comment: Thank you Mark for your answers. 1) So is it possible to resolve 0.1mm features at 15cm distance on a 2cm wide object? 2)  I am interested in the optical specs of the scanner. There is no info anywhere about its imaging capabilities. This information must be available somewhere.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't try anything under 1 cm - regarding the camera, some information was posted in this thread -- https://plus.google.com/118297732182242774648/posts/MgoLn88GcYk